# Moving items up and down in a QListWidget in different view

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to move the listwidget item programmatically. I am able to move the listwidget successfully if the move is in current view. If i try to move the list widget item across view ( i.e Using scrollbar ), move is not working as expected. i.e List widget item is not reflecting

code snip:

```
void func(int fromPage, int toPage)
{
 QListWidget* expListWidget =i.next();
 QListWidgetItem* widgetItem = expListWidget->takeItem(fromPage);
 expListWidget->insertItem(toPage,widgetItem);
}
```

Comment: You should provide more information. If you move it programmatically why do you mention a scroll bar? What do you expect your "code snip" to do? What actually happens? Create a working example reproducing your problem.

Comment: Giving more information: Assume I have 50 list widget item. I can see only 3 list widget item alone. To view others i have to scroll. If I move the the list widget item within view (i.e I am moving second list widget item to first item widget item ) with the above snippet. It is moving second list widget item to first item widget successfully. If i try to move across view (i.e Moving 45th list widget item to 2nd list widget item), nothing happens (i.e The 45th item remains 45th item, 2nd list widget item remains 2nd item)

Comment: Could you provide your code where you do move items between "views"? The code from above only changes places two near items.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to move items up and down independently of where they are located:

```
QListWidget* lw1 = new QListWidget;

for (int i = 0; i < 500 ; i++)
{
    QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(QString::number(i));
    lw1->addItem(item);
}

//move from lower part to the top
QListWidgetItem* i = lw1->takeItem(400);
lw1->insertItem(0, i);

//move from the top to the lower part of the list
i = lw1->takeItem(1);
lw1->insertItem(400, i);
```

Comment: I attached a widget to my item, using setItemWidget.
When i move my items, the attached widget disapear. Any tips using item widgets ?

Comment: @ErwanDouaille did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: @nabroyan sure, it was due to a bad remove from one of my function.
As i remember i removed the widget and create a new one and set the position of it inside the list

Comment: @ErwanDouaille yes, you're right. Also, I have found [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/21748-Problem-with-QListWidget) describing the same thing.