# Swap items in QListWidget using std::swap

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

Is it safe to swap QListWidget items using std swap? Like in this example:

```
int i = ui->listWidget2->currentRow();
if (i > 0)  //currently selected
{ 
    auto current_item = ui->listWidget2->currentItem();
    auto previous_item = ui->listWidget2->item(i-1);
    std::swap(*current_item,*previous_item);
    ui->listWidget2->repaint(); // force repaint, else will not show change
}
```

I must also force repaint it, because result is not shown immediatelly. It works, but is it safe to use that? Can it cause some memory problems, like leaks?

Comment: Swapping the contents of pointers to instances managed under the hood elsewhere (in the list widget) - this is in fact something I would call dangerous. You don't know whether the list widget manages other surrounding data which is related to them. To do it properly, I would remove and re-insert one of these items.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Moving items up and down in a QListWidget in different view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26403020/7478597)